# Magento2 throws an incompatible arguement type error during compilation

Tags: checkout

See below for the code which throws the error.

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\RedExpress\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;

/**
 * Custom shipping model
 */
class Redexpress extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'redexpress';

    protected $_curl;

    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    private $rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    private $rateMethodFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $curl, $data);

        $this->rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->_curl = $curl;
    }
```

Please, I would appreciate a solution to this problem as i am very new to working with magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor PHP Doc you have the curl missing.

Try this :

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $curl, $data);

    $this->rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    $this->_curl = $curl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You donot need defining the variable protected `$_logger;$_logger` etc as it already exists at extended class.

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\RedExpress\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;

class Redexpress extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{

    protected $_code = 'redexpress';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
     */
    private $curl;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, 
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
            array $data = array()
            ) {
        $this->curl = $curl;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);

    }

    public function collectRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
    {

    }

    public function getAllowedMethods(): array {

    }

}
```